# Selenium WebDriver and Highchart testing

Tags: java, html, selenium, highcharts, selenium-webdriver

I know this question has been asked before on S.O. and other websites but I haven't found a definite answer -- most of them say its not easily done but I wanted to make sure that was the final verdict.

Here's my situation:

I'm testing a website that is using Highcharts (http://www.highcharts.com) using Selenium WebDriver (Java).

I basically want to grab the information that is displayed in a small tooltip pop-up that appears when you hover your mouse over each datapoint on the Highchart's line graph.

Looking at the web page's HTML code, I noticed there is `<g class="highcharts-tooltip"...`. I also noticed that, as you move your mouse, the `(X,Y)` values in `...transform="translate(X,Y)">` change, which then changes the information displayed in the tool tip.

Knowing this, my approach would be to somehow grab all the `(X,Y)` values and plug them into the `transform` fields and grab the tooltip data. But I don't know how to programmatically grab all the `(X,Y)` values through Selenium.

Has anyone tackles this issue in the past or has a better way to grab the necessary information?

Answer (score 4):

I started creating a library to work with HighCharts, what I currently have is available here:

https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey/tree/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/selenium/graphs

It's quite hard to provide a generic library that deals with HighCharts as the customisation options on the individual charts can modify the SVG markup quite a bit.  Hopefully the above will help to a degree.

As I do more it will be updated.

Comment: @Ardecsco, great work. I ported your java over to C# and it works a treat. I made a few tweaks and it can also support a chart with multiple lines. If you are interested, I could port it back to Java and make a pull request.

Comment: I thought that already had support for multiple lines, maybe I have forgotten to push something (or I'm just wrong).  Either way I'm always happy to have pull requests :)

Comment: I've got to say, i've learnt so much from your git repo this past week about using selenium and coding in general. thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The Line Charts have to have a background to work. If the chart is created with .setBackgroundColour(null), then the "rect" is not added to the html.

I was able to to add the background colour back in set to the body background colour.  However I'll try and figure out a way of doing it without the "rect".