# How to read the High Charts using Selenium WebDriver Java?

Tags: java, selenium, charts, highcharts

I've been trying to read the data from the Graphs such as below:

1) Line Area Graph
[image: Line Area Graph]

2) Pie Chart
[image: Pie Chart]

3) Bar Chart
[image: Bar Chart]

4) Co-relation Graph
[image: Co-relation Graph]

Above all graphs are made with High Charts(https://www.highcharts.com/).
I've been trying to find a way to read the data using Selenium WebDriver Java and I'm still not able to do so. All the data seems to be dynamic and almost impossible to read.

I've also tried using the below classes and it is retrieving me null values.
https://github.com/Ardesco/Powder-Monkey/tree/master/src/main/java/com/lazerycode/selenium/graphs

Please post if any other approach can be followed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202731/selenium-webdriver-and-highchart-testing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WebDriver \[Java\]: How to Click on elements within an SVG using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41829000/selenium-webdriver-java-how-to-click-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath)